# LINQ query help - second query on first query results

Tags: linq

I have a table of product test results, MfgTests. The test can fail for a variety of reasons but what I'm interested in is this.

- Total number of tests ran that passed overall
- Number of tests where the door switch failed and never passed
- Number of tests where the door switch failed the first time, but passed at some later time

Each record has a unique UID and date/time entry. The product can be tested multiple times.

What I have so far:

```
var totalPass = (from d in KAKs
                where d.TestResult == "PASS"
                select d);
Console.WriteLine("Total Passing: \t" + totalPass.Count());

var dataPass = (from d in KAKs
                where d.DoorSwitch == "PASS"
                select d);
                Console.WriteLine("Total Door Switch Passes: \t" + dataPass.Count());
var dataFail = (from d in KAKs
                where d.DoorSwitch == "FAIL"
                select d);
                Console.WriteLine("Total Door Switch Fails: \t" + dataFail.Count());

foreach (var uid in dataFail)
{
    Console.WriteLine(uid.UID);
    var distinctPass =
        from list in dataPass
        group list by list.UID into grouped
        where grouped.Count() == 1
        select grouped;
        Console.WriteLine("Door Switch Fail but pass later: \t" + distinctPass.Count());
```

This gives me the first two items but I am having a hard time with the last one.

I created a test table to illustrate.

[image]

This is returning:

- Total Passing:   6
- Total Door Switch Passes:   7
- Total Door Switch Fails:   2
- Door Switch Fail but pass later:   4 <- BUT THIS should be 1 result for UID 10

Thought I had it. This works on my test data but not my real data.

```
var distinctPass =
    from list in dataPass
    group list by list.UID into grouped
    where grouped.Count() != 1
    select grouped;
Console.WriteLine("Door Switch Fail but pass later: \t" + distinctPass.Count());
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's my solution, hopefully it helps someone it the future.

```
static IEnumerable<T> CreateEmptyEnumerable<T>(IEnumerable<T> templateQuery)
{
    return Enumerable.Empty<T>();
}

var totalPass = (from d in KAKs
                 where d.TestResult == "PASS"
                 select d);
Console.WriteLine("Total Passing: \t" + totalPass.Count());

var dataPass = (from d in KAKs
                where d.DoorSwitch == "PASS"
                select d);
Console.WriteLine("Total Door Switch Passes: \t" + dataPass.Count());

var failUIDs = (from d in KAKs
                where d.DoorSwitch == "FAIL"
                select d);
Console.WriteLine("Total Door Switch Fails: \t" + failUIDs.Count());

var finalResults = CreateEmptyEnumerable(failUIDs);
var finalPass = CreateEmptyEnumerable(failUIDs);
var finalFail = CreateEmptyEnumerable(failUIDs);

var passfailCount = 0;
var passCount = 0;
var failCount = 0;

DumpContainer dc = new();

foreach (var item in failUIDs)
{
    finalPass = (from d in KAKs
                 where d.DoorSwitch == "PASS"
                 where d.UID == item.UID
                 select d);
    finalFail = (from d in KAKs
                 where d.DoorSwitch == "FAIL"
                 where d.UID == item.UID
                 select d);
                 
    finalResults = finalPass;
    finalResults = finalPass.Union(finalFail);
    
    dc.AppendContent(finalResults);
    finalResults.Count();
    if (finalPass.Count() != 0 && finalFail.Count() != 0)
    {
        passfailCount++;
    }
    else if (finalPass.Count() == 0 && finalFail.Count() != 0)
    {
        failCount++;
    }
    else if (finalPass.Count() != 0 && finalFail.Count() == 0)
    {
        passCount++;
    }
}
Console.WriteLine("Pass/Fail: " + passfailCount);
Console.WriteLine("Pass: " + passCount);
Console.WriteLine("Fail: " + failCount);
//dc.Dump();
```